# What is wrong with this orderByChild Firebase realtime code?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This code is returning an error. Can anyone please guide me on what is wrong with it?

```
DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Doctor");

dbRef.keepSynced(true);

DatabaseReference dbRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Patient").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
Query query = dbRef.orderByChild("filter").equalTo(passed,dbRef2.child("location").toString());

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DoctorHelperClass> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DoctorHelperClass>()
                .setQuery(query, DoctorHelperClass.class).build();
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely here:

```
Query query = dbRef.orderByChild("filter").equalTo(passed,dbRef2.child("location").toString());
```

In case there are multiple nodes with the same `filter` value., the second parameter to `equalTo` is used to further limit the results returned. It does **not** indicate the name of the property to filter on, which you may seem to think.

The full path to filter on, needs to be in the call to `orderByChild`. So if you want to order/filter on the `filter/location` property of each child node, that'd be:

```
Query query = dbRef.orderByChild("filter/location").equalTo(passed);
```

---

**Update**: since you indicated wanting to order/filter on two properties.

Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. In your case for example you could order/filter on `"location_specialization": "locationValue_specializationValue"`.

For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Comment: but I want it to equate to two different values. Apart from the location, I want to compare the specialization as well. How can I do that?

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. In your case for example you could order/filter on `"location_specialization": "locationValue_specializationValue"`. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase